# Magento : add script phtml to product page

Tags: magento

I have a `phtml` script that I want to add it to the product page view right under the price-box div or the content this img describe where I want to add it in the page source :

[image]

I have tried this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">

        <catalog_product_view>
              <reference name="product.info">
                <block type="core/template" name="customprice" as="other" template="customprice/extJs.phtml"/>
              </reference>
        </catalog_product_view>
    </layout>
```

but nothing is done!  Can you explain why and how to fix it?

Comment: See http://www.redlightblinking.com/blog/magento-debugging-how-to-debug-template-paths-logging-and-display-errors here you will know how to find file path you have to work on.

Comment: Did you call it as childhtml?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi if u know how just tell me i don't have much time !!!

Comment: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>. With this you can have your block called

Comment: @DushyantJoshi its not a block its just javascript/php that modify html element in product page 

note: don't wanna modify the core !

Comment: have your tried this <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>. is it a core change? I do not think so

Comment: Post your view.phtm else

Comment: where to put the <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>  ?

Comment: In your view.phtml file. catalog/product/view.phtml

Comment: this is design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule/extJs.phtml : <script type="text/javascript">
// <input type="text" size="100" name="cp" title="custom price" value="400"/>
//<![CDATA[

 $$('#product-price-'+ <?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); ?>).each (function(elem){
     $(elem).hide();
 });

 $('product-price-'+ <?php echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); ?>).show();
 document.getElementById('product-price-'+ <?php Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); ?>)
 .update('<p>TEST !!</p>').innerHTML;

//]]>
</script>

Comment: i m using this script to modify the default price.phtml (add the script under price bow div) :

Comment: See you have prepared your js.phtml file and put it in "catalog_product_view" block. By this it wont be printed/called automatically. You need to have this called and thats by calling getChildHtml function

Comment: There is already a `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>` in view.phtml file by default.

Comment: i just wanna know where ti call the getChildHtml without modifying core ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` file

Change the name from "other" to "otherjs" in your xml

```
    <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                    <div class="short-description">
                        <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                        <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                        <div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('otherjs');//changes here?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: my fault the phtml file name was Jscript.phtml not extJs i m stupid monkey, it s working fine now without <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('otherjs'); thank you man for ur time :)

Comment: do u want to see the result ?

Comment: added it ^^ ____________